# How to properly install ratchet using composer on windows?

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, ratchet

I've been trying to sort this out for weeks and still couldn't get it right. I just get to know composer once I started to explore Ratchet, thus its confusing as to where should get it installed.

1) Where to install composer.phar file? Soe says to the root of my project. Some says to where the php installed in my machine.

I installed composer.phar by clicking on the Composer-Setup.exe here:
https://getcomposer.org/download/

And this gets it installed in `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar`

Now my ratchet project is located here: `C:\projects\rachet\index.php`
Currently there's no other file other than `index.php` which is empty.

2) How to install ratchet now into this path? 
   path = `C:\projects\rachet\index.php`

3) in which command prompt I should type to install ratchet or composer in windows? Currently there are two. one is `php.exe` command prompt and the other is opened by typing `cmd`.

Answer (score 9):

For those whom still looking for an answer for the above question, do the following:

1. click to download composer.exe from official composer page, the link also provided by ratchet
2. upon installation, the composer.phat is installed in your computers /AppData/ComposerSetup
3. open cmd, type `composer install -d <path to your project>` to set your project folder as your current path
4. then type `composer require cboden/ratchet` and wait
5. you'll see vendor folder inside your project folder now, do not close the terminal (cmd)
6. If you didn't do the step in 2) you'll see vendor folder created inside path mentioned in 2)
7. next create `chat.php` and `socket.php` outside of vendor folder: refer here for the files' content: https://web.archive.org/web/20161122141317/http://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/
8. open cmd, type `php <path to your project>/socket.php` :namely `php c:/...../socket.php`
   This is to get the server script running.
9. in the same folder create a php file with this content taken from Ratchet:

```
<script>
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/chat');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
</script>
```

Open console tab and see new messages displayed here.
How to type the message, install simple WebSocket client extension in Chrome and Firefox to type the message